# Read a sequence of numbers of undefined size & print the largest number & position of its first occurrence

Tags: kotlin

I need to read a sequence of numbers of undefined size & prints the largest number & the position of its first occurrence

Can anyone help with this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner

fun main() {
    val scan = Scanner(System.`in`)
    val num = scan.nextInt()
    var max = Int.MIN_VALUE
    var pos = 0
    var i = 1

    do {
        if (max < num) {
            max = num
            pos = i
        }
        i++
    } while (scan.hasNext())

    print("$max $pos")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to read a new number in each iteration:

```
import java.util.Scanner

fun main() {
    val scan = Scanner(System.`in`)
    var max = Int.MIN_VALUE
    var pos = 0
    var i = 1

    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        // Read a new number here
        val num = scan.nextInt()
        if (max < num) {
            max = num
            pos = i
        }
        i++   
    }
    
    print("$max $pos")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### My solution to this task

> This is a simple task, it can be solved in a simple way without using a “java.util.Scanner”. You just need to read a new number in each iteration.

```
fun main() {
    var pos = 0
    var max = 0
    var count = 1    
    while (true) {
        val input = readlnOrNull()
        if (input == null) break
        val num = input.toInt()
        if (pos == 0 || num > max) {
            max = num
            pos = count
        }
        count++   
    }
    print("$max $pos")
}
```